# What is the difference between adding and multiplying fixed effects in linear mixed-effects models such as lme4

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme

Short question – What is the difference between these two linear mixed-effects models:

```
lme4::lmer(duration ~ stress*city*run + (1 | participantID), 
           s2data)

lme4::lmer(duration ~ stress + city*run + (1 | participantID), 
           s2data)
```

Detailed question:
I have a dataset from a virtual user study where participants performed a route-following task from an origin to a destination. Every participant conducted two runs in two different cities in a counterbalanced order. The route in the two cities were of different lengths. Half of the participants were tested under the influence of an additional stressor.

My goal is to determine if a learning effect can be found with increasing task experience, either across all participants or across one of the two stress groups. Here is a glimpse at the data structure:

participantID, stress, city, run, duration

[image: Data Structure]

I came up with the two different linear mixed-effects models, using lme4-package in RStudio (see *Short question*).
When multiplying all fixed effects, there is no significant difference between the different runs.
However, when using stress + city*run, there is a significant difference between the different runs.

Can anyone tell me the differences between these two approaches and which approach makes more sense to determine a potential learning effect with increasing task experience? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Not sure if I understand what you mean. The formula is stated under "Short question". In the detailed question, I explain what the variables stand for and what I'd like to determine with the linear mixed-effects model.

Comment: You ask what the difference in the formulas are in the short question; `?formula` provides a detailed discussion of formula notation including interactions, which I thought may be useful

Comment: Thank you, I now understood your input! :) So if I interpret the ?formula correctly, it doesn't make much sense to use stress + city*run, referring to my question. What are your thoughts on that?

Comment: Thank you very much!